# How make "bold" data labels in GGPubr?

Tags: r, data-visualization, ggpubr

I want bold values inside ggbarplot, but i really don't know how. yscale has to be "percent"

```
x <- pierwsze %>%
  group_by(treatment_groups,sex) %>%
  count() %>%
  ggpubr::ggbarplot(
    x = "treatment_groups",
    fill = "sex",
    y = "n",
    label = TRUE, lab.col = "black", lab.vjust = 1.2,
    position = position_fill(),
    palette = get_palette(palette = "Oranges",5)
  )+
  labs(x="Treatment Group",y="Proportion",fill="Sex")+
  yscale("percent",.format = TRUE)+
  font("xy.text",size=10)
```

Comment: Welcome to stack overflow. It’s easier to help if you make your question reproducible: include a minimal dataset in the form of an object for example if a data frame as df <- data.frame(…) where … is your variables and values or use dput(head(df, n)) in the case of larger datasets. These links should be of help: [mre] and [ask]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is a solution for printing labels in bold.

```
q <- ggplot_build(x)
x + geom_text(data=q$data[[2]], aes(x=x, y=y, label=label), 
    fontface="bold", vjust=1.2)
```

[image]

Comment: Thanks, this solution saved my life :D